# How to pass values from fragment to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it ok to call another fragment from fragment and pass var City with such way?
or i should use interfaces or ...

code:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment(City).commit();
```

and the fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment  {

private City city;

public HomeFragment(){}

public HomeFragment(City c){
    city = c;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) { ....
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not OK, you should pass parameters to fragments using Fragment.setArguments, which accepts Bundle. So you must be able to convert City to Bundle. This is because system might want to recreate your Fragment and then it uses arguments to initialize it, you call then getArguments() in your fragment.

This could be acceptable if your fragment was retained. It was created with setRetainInstance(true).

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use `fragment.setArguments(Bundle bundle)` method to pass parameters or use interface like in this tutorial : [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)